# Mapping cartesian coordinates to circular coordinates

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems

I have some "rectangular" x,y coordinates which I like to convert to "circular" coordinates. Notice I'm not sure if I'm using the correct terms here, so bear with me - I drew an example to show how the mapping is to be done:

[image: ..]

Excuse the horrible drawing, I didn't have any tools as well, but I hope it is understandable. Basically, I want to convert any point $P$ into the corresponding $Q$ point. I can easily construct a triangle inside the unit circle as seen, but the problem is determining the length $l$ of the hypotenuse:
$$
P=\left(x,y\right)\\ \theta=atan2\left(P_x,P_y\right)\\ r=\left|P\right|\\ l=r?\\ \\ Q_x=l\cdot cos\left(\theta\right)\\ Q_y=l\cdot sin\left(\theta\right)
$$

If I simply treat $P$ as a vector and use the magnitude of that as the length, I'm back to where I started ($P=Q$ again), since I basically did a cartesian->polar->cartesian conversion.

I realize I can circumvent the problem by defining some function $R(\theta)$ that scales the magnitude according to the phase angle, $\theta$, that would look something like this:

[image: ..]

Derived from the magnitude difference between $P$ and $Q$. The length $l$ would then be:

$$
l=\left|P\right|\cdot R(\theta)
$$

But this seems kinda weird, and I'm not sure how to construct the function $R(\theta)$ (I just drew what I thought it would look like). I'm pretty sure I'm just missing something basic - in any case, I would be very grateful for any help.

Regards

Comment: Just to be clear, you want a vector in polar coordinates that is _not_ generally the same length as your input vector, right? If the $P$ vector has coordinates $(x,y),$ it looks like you want the length of the $Q$ vector to be either $x$ or $y$, whichever is greater. Is that a correct statement of the problem?

Comment: I'm not completely sure if "either x or y, whichever is greater" will yield the correct length (although that would seem to be the case)? But yes.

Comment: In fact, one might be able to define $R(\theta)$ from $max(cos(\theta), sin(\theta))$.. Hmm

Comment: To put it another way, in the first picture it looks like you draw a perpendicular line from your $P$ point to the nearest coordinate axis, and then draw a circular arc starting at that point on that axis. Then the radius of that arc would be equal to the coordinate where that perpendicular line meets the axis.

Comment: If I guessed correctly then I think you have the right formula for $R(\theta)$ now.

Comment: Okay, so actually just having $l=max(|x|,|y|)$ worked - abs added so it works in all four quadrants. Thanks for dropping the penny!